# Some emails show blank on Squirrelmail

Tags: squirrelmail

For some reason certain messages, only for some users, are showing up either partially or totally blank and are not selectable. The mail server is not self hosted ([migadu.com](https://migadu.com)), only Squirrelmail (v 1.4.22).

I've confirmed the messages themselves seem just fine and are perfectly fine when downloaded via another IMAP client. I'm guessing it's something specific about these messages, but I can't figure out what to look for.

I saw some other posts talking about similar things and they seemed to point to a permissions issue, but I can't figure out what permissions I should be setting, and wasn't sure if those suggestions related to the actual mail servers.

See screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the header encoding on those messages and PHP decoding issues. The problem is solved by installing a snapshot version of SquirrelMail 1.4.23-svn from the [download page](https://squirrelmail.org/download.php) which is recommended anyway.

@RogerTheShrubber and @Nirmal no, SquirrelMail is not deprecated and yes, it is under active development. If you think you find a bug or other problem, please reach out to us through our [mailing lists or issue tracker](https://squirrelmail.org/docs/admin/admin-12.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually SquirrelMail webmail client is already depreciated, hence there woun't  be any bug fixes for this within the server.

I recommend you to use other webmail client apart from (SquirrelMail), check with your Mail service provider for further details.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not under development. The current version came out in 2013. So I didn't expect that someone would come with bug fixes. I posted wondering if others had encountered the issue and knew of the reason or a workaround. As far as alternatives, I needed (for reasons that aren't interesting or important) something that was less reliant on more modern web tech. So that's why I went with Squirrelmail.